# how to create an xsl file which access a properties file in order for an xml to xml file transformation

Tags: xslt, properties

Consider an xml file as

```
<Content>
  <abc>....</abc>
</Content>
```

I have a properties file with suppose

```
 abc=def
```

and my final transformed xml file looks like

```
<Content>
  <def>....</def>
</Content>
```

so my xsl file which transformes the first xml file should make use of the above properties file and transform it. Can anyone suggest how can we achive this using XSLT?

Comment: There is no way to access a non-XML file with XSLT alone. What other programming languages do you have? Also, **what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the properties file in XML format, for instance

```
<Properties>
    <Property value="abc">def</Property>
    <Property value="...">...</Property>
</Properties>
```

then you can use xslt to process both XML files and replace abc elements with def ones, etcetera.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="props" select="document('Properties.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Content/*">
        <xsl:variable name="repl" select="$props/Properties/Property[@value=name(current())]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$repl">
                <xsl:element name="{$repl}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
  <abc>xxx</abc>
  <def>zzz</def>
  <ghi>ccc</ghi>
</Content>
```

with Properties file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    <Property value="abc">def</Property>
    <Property value="def">www</Property>
</Properties>
```

this results in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Content>
    <def>xxx</def>
    <www>zzz</www>
    <ghi>ccc</ghi>
</Content>
```

**ADDITION by Jeevan**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
      My question is that if i want to access 
         'value' attribute(input xml file tags) 

     ex:       
                  <Property value="abc">def</Property>
```

I want 'abc' to be accessed from Properties.xml file in someother variable say 'repl1', using something like '$props/Properties/..' in select?
how can this be achieved.

**ANSWER by Maestro13**

Still unclear what you wish to do, so I will just give you some hints which are hopefully useful.

The value attribute can be accessed by an Xpath expression including `/@value`. You need to have a current Property node to be able to that of course. This may be done by either doing a loop as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$props/Properties/Property">
    <w><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></w>
</xsl:for-each>
```

where the current node within the loop is the one looped over, and `@value` acts on that node.
Or you may define a template doing the same (a template, unless named and called directly, will be called repetitvely for all matching nodes).
Another way to retrieve the value attribute is first have an Xpath expression that selects exactly one Property element, for instance by selecting the n-th occurrence as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$props/Properties/Property[3]/@value"/>
```

In case of the above Properties file, this will return `ghi`.

Comment: @Maestro13: can't we access the 'value' attribute from Properties.xml file in someother variable say 'repl1', using something like '$props/Properties/..' in select?

Comment: @Maestro13:Can you please send me the solution ASAP. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jeevan what exactly are you trying to achieve? Best update the question itself to explain this, then I can update my answer :-).

Comment: @Maestro13: i just updated your answer with a question which deals with my requirement. Please check out and give me the solution for it.

Comment: @Maestro13: thats a perfect solution for what i need, thanks.